# POJO representation from JSON

Tags: java, json, pojo

Firstly forgive me as I think this is a stupid question. I just started learning java

I have a json file of which I parsed it to POJO so that I can do operations on them

this is the parser implementation

```
public class ParsingTweet {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    assert args != null & args.length > 0;
    List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<>();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            tweets.add(mapper.readValue(line, Tweet.class));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(tweets);
 }
}
```

but my instructor said this result is not the actual POJO. its just a string representation. For example

```
[[text = I think this would be good. Would hopefully light the fire in the later rounds if you knew you were losing..., created_at = Mon Mar 06 22:48:07 +0000 2017, user = User@56f4468b, coordinates = null], [text = @Night_0f_Fire He's stuck in the alimony machine,, bust him out, created_at = Mon Mar 06 22:47:53 +0000 2017, user = User@6cc4c815, coordinates = null], ..., ..., ...]]]
```

so what does the actual POJO look like?

PS. this is the example json

{"text": "Flood/Storm/Tree Down. Northern Beaches (King Rd, Ingleside, NSW 2101) at 6 Mar 2017 21:38 , "user": {"id": "4721717942", "name": "NSW Fire Updates"}, "lang": "en", "coordinates": { "coordinates": [151.264811, -33.6848] , "type":"Point"}, "created_at": "Mon Mar 06 10:44:31 +0000 2017"}, ..., ...

Comment: Plain Old Java Object. The instructor probably wants you to do marshaling

Comment: You assume that each line is a separate json? This seems very stange. However, if that's ok, then your tweets list is ok and indeed contains just simple java structure objects.

Comment: I parsed it line-by-line. my instructore said that all the POJO(s) is stored in List<Tweet> tweets but I also print System.out.println(tweets) so how can this is not the actual POJO? The task is simply just parsing. I didnt have to print it actually, its not a requirement. But i was just curious what it actually looks like

Comment: Could you show us the content of the file (maybe only a few lines) to understand what you want to parse.

Comment: sure i just updated it

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson for example.

```
String fullFile = ...read file...;
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Tweet> tweets = gson.fromJson(fullFile, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Tweet>>(){});
System.out.println(tweets);
```